# OroCommerce: Configurable Product display in storefront and backoffice

Tags: orocommerce

I've created configurable product (internet connection with different speed) following docs, in storefront I see [dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFYTH.png) with product vairants, all is ok.
But in backoffice (when editing shoppingList or creating order) there is always only one variant of product with no ability to quickly select another option (eg change speed to another one) - is this how oro backoffice works and nothing could be changed to make backoffice user quickly navigate between product variants (eg change speed from 1M to 2M by clients phone request)?
[Cant even edit product in shopping list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUyjS.png)

UPD:
If there's no way to see user-friendly configurable product in backoffice than I need to implement smth like button near each product in LineItem which will show popup with product variants. When user will select another option request will be sent to some route and it will run smth like `$lineItem->setProduct($newProduct);` , grid reloaded and new product variant selected. Is it ok or it will break something in oro?
Where to start for adding that button and popup? Eg I cant edit oro shopping list template, how to properly extend it?

Answer (score 0):

On the line item editing form you cannot change the product, no matter it's configurable or simple. It's done intentionally.

If you want to change the product, you always can remove a line item and add the new one with updated options manually:

[image]

Comment: Okay, I got it about LineItem, but still wonder is it possible in backoffice to see Configurable Product same way as its in storefront, eg single product with options instead of separate variants of product?